# JS Chart framework for integer against time

Tags: javascript, charts

What would you suggest for a JS framework to plot line chart using the input below.Using google chart with the code below does not work with time value.

`gridVdata =[["11:23:09","6.300000"],["10:47:26","6.300000"],["13:09:36","6.310000"],
["12:31:00","6.400000"],["11:38:45","6.300000"],["12:29:03","6.400000"],
["11:38:45","6.310000"],["12:17:47","6.390000"],["13:54:30","6.310000"],
["14:15:40","6.340000"]];`

```
google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart', 'line'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBackgroundColor);
function drawBackgroundColor() {
   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
   data.addColumn('number', 'X');
   data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');
   data.addRows(gridVdata);
   var options = {
       hAxis: {
               title: 'Price'
              },
              vAxis: {
                title: 'Volume'
             },
            backgroundColor: '#f1f8e9'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

I could have used any framework but because of the time value, I just don't have a clue. Any advice in the right direction will help.

Answer (score 0):

the reason it's not working, the columns are both defined as `'number'`

```
data.addColumn('number', 'X');
data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');
```

but the values in the array are all strings

```
["11:23:09","6.300000"]
```

if you change the first column to `'string'`,
and lose the quotes on the values in the second instance of the arrays,
the chart will draw...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawBackgroundColor();
    window.addEventListener('resize', drawBackgroundColor, false);
  },
  packages:['corechart', 'table']
});

function drawBackgroundColor() {
  var gridVdata = [
    ["11:23:09",6.300000],["10:47:26",6.300000],["13:09:36",6.310000],
    ["12:31:00",6.400000],["11:38:45",6.300000],["12:29:03",6.400000],
    ["11:38:45",6.310000],["12:17:47",6.390000],["13:54:30",6.310000],
    ["14:15:40",6.340000]
  ];

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');
  data.addRows(gridVdata);
  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Price'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Volume'
    },
    backgroundColor: '#f1f8e9'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

if you wanted to use column type `'timeofday'`

```
data.addColumn('timeofday', 'X');
```

you could change the values in the first instance of the arrays,
to an array of time values

```
[[11,23,9],6.300000]
```

just need to sort the data before drawing,

```
data.sort([{column: 0}]);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawBackgroundColor();
    window.addEventListener('resize', drawBackgroundColor, false);
  },
  packages:['corechart', 'table']
});

function drawBackgroundColor() {
  var gridVdata = [
    [[11,23,9],6.300000],[[10,47,26],6.300000],[[13,09,36],6.310000],
    [[12,31,00],6.400000],[[11,38,45],6.300000],[[12,29,03],6.400000],
    [[11,38,45],6.310000],[[12,17,47],6.390000],[[13,54,30],6.310000],
    [[14,15,40],6.340000]
  ];

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('timeofday', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');
  data.addRows(gridVdata);
  data.sort([{column: 0}]);
  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Price'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Volume'
    },
    backgroundColor: '#f1f8e9'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```